# Background authenticated google sheets api to edit and read format of a cell

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I do have an existing spreadsheet for the task, which is being used right now without any client.

I would like for my client to read format information (background color) and edit cell values, which I can get to work.

The problem is that my users don't necessarily have a google account, with which they could authenticate themselves. So all the examples on the google site don't cover my use case.

How can I avoid authentication (the spreadsheet is public) while reading format information and edit cell values with my JavaScript app (which is targeted to be a Cordova App)?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a solution that utilizes a service account that owns, edits, and reads the data from the spreadsheet. That said, if users aren't interacting with the spreadsheet directly then you may be better off just using a database to store the information.

Comment: The users are also using the spreadsheet directly. Could you provide some more information or maybe a link to the service account solution? This service account could authenticate itself in the background of the app?

Answer (score 0):

For reading: this is effectively the same as [Google Sheets API v4 receives HTTP 401 responses for public feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315266/google-sheets-api-v4-receives-http-401-responses-for-public-feeds).  We'll be allowing reading fully public sheets w/o requiring auth in the near future.

For writing: I'm uncertain if we'll also support editing of those sheets without auth.  You may need to use credentials in order to write.

Comment: Is there a way to use my credentials in the background instead of asking the user?