# How to make POST requests to google spreadsheets using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I am trying to post some data from the client side to the google spreadsheet. After looking hard through their documentation for v4 I haven't found a way.

Comment: Which server side language you use? They have given some language options but php and java script  https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/php , https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/js might help?

Comment: Im using javascript, however those links have very limited methods and no POST option.

Comment: Did you find the Solution For that ? @psheth

Answer (score 11):

**How to Write to to a Cell Using Spreadsheet API in JS**

In essence, you have to know [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). I'll give you an example. 
Let's say you want to write to A1:B1 range of your spreadsheet, say [A1]Hello [B1]World.

Your URI request would look like this:

```
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SPREADSHEET_ID}/values/Sheet1!A1:B1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
```

request body:

```
{
           "range":"Sheet1!A1:B1",
           "majorDimension": "ROWS",
           "values": [
           ["Hello"," World"]
          ]
}
```

Did this in oauthplayground using Google Sheetsv4 and it worked.
[image]

**How to apply this in JS?**

After setting up the [JS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/js) find a way to call this inside a function:

```
var params = {
           "range":"Sheet1!A1:B1",
           "majorDimension": "ROWS",
           "values": [
           ["Hello","World"]
          ],
     }
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('PUT', 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SPREADSHEET_ID}/values/Sheet1!A1:B1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

Also read [Reading & Writing cells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/values) in Sheets v4. Hope this crash course helps.

Comment: While Trying your code am Getting error as `ReferenceError: access_token is not defined`   How can i solve that @noogui

Comment: @Becky that's because access_token is my user-defined variable.   var access_token = 'ya29.CabcdabcdefgkMHMeDNxC1koDhrS3fM-7pjzMFAfCgVPxnNM2dAxyzaldlRBvxKLcyA';  ..You have to find a way to generate your own.

Comment: Thanks....and  I don't know how to create my own access_token ? How can i make that ? Any idea's  ?

Comment: @Becky follow my other guide [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315266/google-sheets-api-v4-receives-http-401-responses-for-public-feeds).

Comment: If Possible can you pls Answer for that --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096279/inserting-datas-into-google-sheets-api-using-javascript

Comment: Remember, that access token from oAuthPlayground is good for only 1 hour.