# Nodejs Google Sheets API

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

Does anyone know where to find a good example of using the Google Sheets API to write to a google sheet? I've used https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs, and was successfully to able to read from a Google Sheets, but am having trouble figuring out how to write to a Google Sheets.

Answer (score 4):

The below works for me, assuming you have already gotten an authorized oAuth2Client.

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', oAuth2Client});

async function writeSample() {
  let title = "NewSpreadsheet";
  try {
    var spreadsheet = await createSheet(title);
    console.log(`Spreadsheet ID: ${spreadsheet.spreadsheetId}`);

    range = "Sheet1!A1:D5";
    let valueInputOption = "RAW";
    values = [
      ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
      ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],
      ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
      ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"],
      ["Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)"]
    ];
    var result = await writeSheet(spreadsheet.spreadsheetId, range, valueInputOption, values);
    console.log('%d cells updated.', result.updatedCells);
    return result;
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function createSheet(title) {
  var resource = {
    properties: {
      title
    },
  };
  return sheets.spreadsheets.create({ resource, fields: 'spreadsheetId', })
    .then(response => response.data);
}

async function writeSheet(spreadsheetId, range, valueInputOption, values, ) {
  resource = {
    values
  };
  return sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({ spreadsheetId, range, valueInputOption, resource, })
    .then(response => response.data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sheets API has sample with regard to [Writing a single range](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing) on google sheets. There are concepts you must understand though like [A1 Notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation).

Aside from the samples from the guide, I also wrote JS codes to demonstrate writing on sheets on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857531/how-to-make-post-requests-to-google-spreadsheets-using-javascript/38871487#38871487). This will be helpful as NodejS uses JS too.

Comment: Is the access_token the same as the token produced from quickstart.js? I tried following your example, using that access token. My code runs fine but nothing is written to the Google Sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have also read noogui's references: it will take some time before you have a finished program.

But I have succeeded in doing the following functions:

```
    appedData ()
    deleteRow () (I can post them if you wish)
```

I needed to insert: temp, humidity and pressure in a row and in combination delete the oldest row (row 1).
I placed these two functions in the same line where listMajors(...) was originally (in quickstart, js). And then put it into a loop:
Bad idea:
The functions are asynchronous so you do not know when one is finished and the other begins,
A `console.log()` print showed:

```
 appedData ()
 deleteRow ()
 appedData ()
 deleteRow ()
 deleteRow ()
 appedData ()
 deleteRow ()
 appedData ()
 appedData ()
```

So sometimes appedData() and deleteRow() in real order, sometimes two or more times appedData() in order
And other times two or more times deleteRow() in order.

I therefore changed quickstart.js to synchronous function instead of asynchronous:
I removed callbacks of replaced `fs.readFile` with `fs.readFileSync`,
And it seems to work