# How do I store/send data from a HTML form without using a server side language?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

Essentially, I have a form that has data required to be written to a database/exported or sent to someone. However, I am unable to use a server side language like PHP as this form is hosted on Shopify. I did not use Shopify's form builder or any of the form plugins as there was a lot of logic jumping and calculation in the form. The form was made with Bootstrap + JavaScript for the calculation/logic.

I understand that this might be an impossible task, but no harm trying I guess.

Any solution is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can use session and local storage for this (javascript)

Comment: It's not impossible, you can do it to e.g. Google Sheets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857531/how-to-make-post-requests-to-google-spreadsheets-using-javascript/38871487

Answer (score 1):

You can tryout something like this

```
   <form id="sendNameForm" onSubmit="sendName()">
    <input id="myName" name="name">
    <input type='submit' value='send'/>
   </form>

 function sendName(){
  let name = document.getElementById('myName').value
  localStorage.setItem('name', name)
  }
```

Comment: How do I retrieve the data from the local storage if I do not have access to the PC it is being stored on?

Comment: local storage works with the browser, so you can only access the data from the specific browser in which its stored..

Comment: so I would need to have access to the local browser it's stored in then..? Or is there a way to transmit that stored data over the internet automatically?

Comment: if you would like to send the data automatically to another server after sometime.. you can set that in code basing on some conditions or with a timer.. But i don't see much use case for that