# Add, update works but how to append using iOS Google Sheets API v4?

Tags: ios, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have been trying to implement a basic iOS app that will write to a Google spreadsheet when an event occurs.
I started with Google dev docs here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/ios and was able to get the things working till adding data and updating it.
But, I am not able to find a way to **append data(insert a new row)**.

I have used `[self.service fetchObjectByUpdatingObject:...` method to accomplish above but `[self.service fetchObjectByInsertingObject:...` method refuses to work on the same lines.

Reference documentation talks about an `append` method for this purpose but I am not finding a way to call it in iOS. I have tried almost all the Fetch Methods provided to us in the `GTLService` class.

**Update:** I am looking for the iOS counterpart for executing the following as done in Java: `service.spreadsheets().values().append`

Any guidance on how to append data to a spreadsheet is much appreciated.

**PS**: I have also tried the standard REST approach but that always returned `Unauthenticated` error. So, I ditched that and took the above approach which worked for add, update.
Let me know if someone needs me to post the code for add, update implementation.

Comment: Try checking if you have [Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing) properly. For private data : [Oauth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing), for public data : an identifier, such as an [API key](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#APIKey) is needed. Every request your application sends to the Google Sheets API needs to identify your application to Google.

Comment: You might also want to check the answer on this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37325295/5995040) about `Unauthorized` request for Google Sheet API v4. Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, I have already given it a go(and will do again), if that is the only way to do it. In the first part of my question, I got it working for Add and Update without using REST services(by using GLTService class). Is there no way to achieve append using the same approach? Thanks

Comment: I mean is there no way to do the append using the GoogleAPIClient library which I used for doing Add and Update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Sheets API iOS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/ios) has been updated to use a newer version of the Objective-C client library that includes generated classes for the Google Sheets API. Using that new library you can make an append call using the following code:

```
    let spreadsheetId = "..."
    let range = "Sheet1"
    let valueRange = GTLRSheets_ValueRange.init();
    valueRange.values = [
        ["Hello", "World"]
    ]
   let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesAppend
            .query(withObject: valueRange, spreadsheetId:spreadsheetId, range:range)
        query.valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED"
        service.executeQuery(query,
                             delegate: self,
                             didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
```

Comment: Yup, this new way is the way to go!! Thanks a lot!