# Google Sheets API v4 append request receives HTTP 401 response for public feeds using API Key

Tags: google-sheets-api

This is extremely similar to another question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37325295) about how to GET spreadsheet data, but I'm trying to **append** data to a spreadsheet. Here's my sample curl request:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"range":"A1","majorDimension":"ROWS","values":["Frank2"]}' https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{SPREADSHEET_ID}/values/A1:append?valueInputOption=RAW&key={API-KEY}
```

Here's the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "The request does not have valid authentication credentials.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Can this be done only using an API Key or am I doing something wrong? The documentation suggests it is possible if the spreadsheet is shared publicly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Requests that write to the spreadsheet require authentication credentials.  Even if the spreadsheet is shared publicly, when writing through the API the write must be attributed to a user.

Comment: where is that stated? I can't find that anywhere in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing

Comment: I have this same problem the documentation says you can use an APIKey.

Comment: yes ?key=API_KEY works only for GET but not for POST

Answer (score 1):

This is currently broken. You can not edit the document (even if public) with only an APIKey.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73974970

Comment: FWIW, per the above answer, write requests intentionally requires user authorization and does not work with only an apikey.  If the documentation states otherwise, can you please point me to those docs?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey

The page above states the following:

> Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.