# Google Sheets API v4, cannot make anonymous PUT request to public document

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Spreadsheet which is shared as "Anyone with the link can EDIT". I want to perform a PUT request to edit this document using the Google Sheets API v4. Ideally, I wish to do this using only an API key and not using OAuth2, since authenticating with Google using OAuth is a pain to get working on Xamarin. Also, this would require the user to enter a password every hour, which would break usability.

Supposedly, [requests for public data can be sent using only the API key in the request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing), not requiring OAuth. This works for GET requests, but I get a 401 response when doing this for the PUT request. ([This unintentionally failed for GET requests before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315266/google-sheets-api-v4-receives-http-401-responses-for-public-feeds), which leads me to believe that this should work for PUT requests as well, as long as the target document is publicly shared).

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{sheetId}/values/Sheet1%21A1%3AJ1?key={myKey} HTTP/1.1
```

...works, but

```
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{sheetId}/values/Sheet1%21A1%3AJ1?key={myKey} HTTP/1.1
```

...yields a 401 Unauthorized.

Is anyone able to shed some light on whether or not this should be possible, or how to work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous writes using the APi are not allowed (they currently require credentials), even if the sheet is shared as 'anyone can edit'.

Comment: Thank you, this settles the question.

Comment: How can I do it without OAuth 2.0? Thank you in advance